# Integral of form $\int \frac{1}{ \sqrt{-a x^2 + b x + c}} dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, rational-functions

I am looking at an integral of the form

$$\int^{x_{\rm max}}_0 \frac{2 \sqrt{a} }{\sqrt{-a x^2 + b x + c}}dx$$

Where the upper limit is given by $x_{\rm max} = \frac{b + \sqrt{b^2 + 4 a c}}{2 a}$. Here $a, b$ and $c$ are all real and $a > 0$ etc. The answer apparently takes the form

\begin{align}
4 \arctan \left(\sqrt{ \frac{\sqrt{b^2 + 4 a c} + b}{\sqrt{b^2 + 4 a c} - b} } \right)
\end{align}

The Euler substitution, completing the square, trig substitutions, etc, do lead to solutions of the form $\arcsin(\cdot)$, and hence $\arctan(\cdot)$ via $$\arcsin(x) = \arctan\frac x {\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
But, I can't seem to get something in the form above. This is a classic integral that can be found in any of the standard tables, e.g. 226 on Pg. 15 of [https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~bishop/classes/math126.F20/CRC_integrals.pdf](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Ebishop/classes/math126.F20/CRC_integrals.pdf). I'm probably doing something silly here. Thanks in advance for any insight here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the Euler substitution
$$\sqrt{-a x^2 + b x + c}=\sqrt a\bigg(x-\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}{2a}\bigg)t$$ and note that the bounds become $(0,x_{max})\to (t_{max},0)$ with
$$t_{max}=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{b^2+4ac}+b}{\sqrt{b^2+4ac}-b}}$$
Then

\begin{align}
\int_0^{x_{max}}\frac{2\sqrt a}{\sqrt{-a x^2 + b x + c}}dx
=\int^{t_{max}}_0\frac{4}{1+t^2}dt= 4 \tan^{-1} (t_{max})
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks @Quanto! As noted above, this was the Euler substitution that had already been tried. The term in the ArgTan doesn't trivially agree with the expression it is apparently meant to. Especially with the divergence as $x \rightarrow 0$. I hope we don't have to appeal to Hadamard or something.

Comment: @user242868 - the Euler substitution above corresponds to the sought-after arctan expression

Comment: That's wonderful! I hadn't seen that in the combos I had tried, much appreciated.